# Metro (MahApps) WPF: Override TabItem style

Tags: c#, wpf, xaml, mahapps.metro

There are a lot of things I like about MahApps Metro for WPF, and there are some I'm less fond of.  One of them is the Metro tab style, so I'm trying to tweak it.  Or write my own, really.

My problem is that while I can create a tab control style, I can't seem to override the TabItem style at all.  I've started simple: Just red, static text, regardless of what's there.  But I can't even get that right.  It keeps using the Metro style.

(Binding is through Caliburn.Micro.)

**ShellView.xaml:**

```
<TabControl Style="{StaticResource TabControlStyle}" DockPanel.Dock="Top"
    x:Name="AvailableTabs">
    <TabControl.ItemTemplate>
        <DataTemplate>
            <TextBlock Text="{Binding DisplayName}" />
        </DataTemplate>
    </TabControl.ItemTemplate>
</TabControl>
```

**Inside App.xaml:**

```
<ResourceDictionary Source="Resources/CustomControls.xaml" />

<!-- MahApps.Metro resource dictionaries. Make sure that all file names are Case Sensitive! -->
<ResourceDictionary Source="pack://application:,,,/MahApps.Metro;component/Styles/Controls.xaml" />
<ResourceDictionary Source="pack://application:,,,/MahApps.Metro;component/Styles/Fonts.xaml" />
<ResourceDictionary Source="pack://application:,,,/MahApps.Metro;component/Styles/Colors.xaml" />
<!-- Accent and AppTheme setting -->
<ResourceDictionary Source="pack://application:,,,/MahApps.Metro;component/Styles/Accents/Blue.xaml" />
<ResourceDictionary Source="pack://application:,,,/MahApps.Metro;component/Styles/Accents/BaseLight.xaml" />
```

**TabControl/Item Styles:**

```
<Style TargetType="TabItem" BasedOn="{StaticResource MetroTabItem}">
    <Setter Property="Background" Value="Red" />
    <Setter Property="Template">
        <Setter.Value>
            <ControlTemplate TargetType="TabItem">
                <TextBlock Text="Tab" />
            </ControlTemplate>
        </Setter.Value>
    </Setter>
</Style>
```

**Result:**
[image: TabControl]

The TabControl's style is definitely working -- the presence of the horizontal line between tabs and content is proof enough of that.  I also tried using `{DynamicResource WhiteBrush}` (from mahapps) in the style to see if maybe it couldn't find mahapps resources, but that worked just fine.  But the tabs themselves are still using the Metro style.

What am I doing wrong?  This is driving me crazy, and I can't shake the feeling that I'm doing something that's both simple, and stupid. :)

(Also, I tried adding `BasedOn={StaticResource MetroTabItem}` to the TabItem style and that didn't work either.)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It's the order in which you reference your global / implicit styles.

The style in `Resources/CustomControls.xaml`

```
<Style TargetType="TabItem" BasedOn="{StaticResource MetroTabItem}">
    <Setter Property="Background" Value="Red" />
    <Setter Property="Template">
        <Setter.Value>
            <ControlTemplate TargetType="TabItem">
                <TextBlock Text="Tab" Padding="10" Margin="1,0" 
                           Background="{TemplateBinding Background}" />
            </ControlTemplate>
        </Setter.Value>
    </Setter>
</Style>
```

is shadowed by the `MahApps` styles, as it is referenced first. It should be the other way around:

**App.xaml**

```
<ResourceDictionary.MergedDictionaries>
    <!-- MahApps.Metro resource dictionaries. Make sure that all file names are Case Sensitive! -->
    <ResourceDictionary Source="pack://application:,,,/MahApps.Metro;component/Styles/Controls.xaml" />
    <ResourceDictionary Source="pack://application:,,,/MahApps.Metro;component/Styles/Fonts.xaml" />
    <ResourceDictionary Source="pack://application:,,,/MahApps.Metro;component/Styles/Colors.xaml" />
    <!-- Accent and AppTheme setting -->
    <ResourceDictionary Source="pack://application:,,,/MahApps.Metro;component/Styles/Accents/Blue.xaml" />
    <ResourceDictionary Source="pack://application:,,,/MahApps.Metro;component/Styles/Accents/BaseDark.xaml" />
    <!-- Last in line will prevail -->
    <ResourceDictionary Source="Resources/CustomControls.xaml" />
</ResourceDictionary.MergedDictionaries>
```